# Collecting metrics on different frequency for Grafana/Prometheus Database exporter

Tags: database, monitoring, grafana, prometheus

I am trying to setup a Prometheus exporter for Oracle Database.
For Database monitoring, I do not want to collect all the metrics every time.
Rather, collect metrics on different frequency.
e.g.
For Databases, CPU need to be monitored almost every minute.
However, For level-0 backup, I need to monitor only once a day.

Is there any way to achieve the same?

***This to protect the DB from getting queried multiple times unnecessarily for a metric that can literally be collected only once a day.***

This is my Grafana configuration file..

```
server:
  log_level: warn
 
metrics:
  global:
    scrape_interval: 60s
    remote_write:
      - url:
        oauth2:
          client_id: 
          client_secret: 
          token_url:
 
  configs:
    - name: default
      scrape_configs:
        - job_name: traces
          honor_labels: true
          static_configs:
            - targets:
        - job_name: oracle_pdb_default
          honor_labels: true
          static_configs:
            - targets:
               - 
              labels:
                service_name: 
                instance: 
                role: "primary"
        - job_name: oracle_cdb_default
          honor_labels: true
          static_configs:
            - targets:
               - 
              labels:
                service_name: 
                instance: 
                role: "primary"
integrations:
  agent:
    enabled: true
  node_exporter:
    enabled: true
    include_exporter_metrics: true
    enable_collectors:
      - "systemd"
```

As per this, the scrape interval is 60s. Due to this, all the metrics get collected every 60 seconds.

Here is my Oracle Node Exporter.

```
cat /opt/custom-metrics-cdb.toml

[[metric]]

context = "index_unusable"

metricsdesc = { count="Gauge metric with count of index_unusable." }

labels = ["segment_name"]

request = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count from dba_indexes, v$database where status not in ('VALID','N/A') and database_role='PRIMARY'"

scrape_interval = "1h"
 
[[metric]]

context = "invalid_objects"

labels = [ "owner","object_name","object_type" ]

metricsdesc = {count="Generic counter metric from CDB_invalid_objects in Oracle." }

request = "select owner,object_name,object_type,count(*) as count from cdb_invalid_objects, v$database where database_role='PRIMARY' group by owner,object_name,object_type"

ignorezeroresult = true
 
[[metric]]

context = "stale_stats_checks"

labels = [ "owner","table_name","object_type" ,"partition_name","last_analyzed"]

metricsdesc = {count="Generic counter metric from CDB_TAB_STATISTICS in Oracle." }

request = "select owner,table_name,object_type,partition_name,to_char(last_analyzed,'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi') last_analyzed,count(*) as count  from CDB_TAB_STATISTICS, v$database where stale_stats = 'YES' and owner not in ('SYS','SYSTEM','DBSNMP','SYSMAN','ODSOGG') and table_name not like '%INTERIM%' and table_name not like '%TEMP%' and owner not like '%XDB%' and last_analyzed< trunc(sysdate-1)+22/24 and database_role='PRIMARY' group by owner,table_name,object_type,partition_name,last_analyzed order by 1,2"
 
 
[[metric]]

context = "number_logs_switches"

labels = [ "period","thread","hour"]

metricsdesc = {count="Generic counter metric in Oracle." }

request = "SELECT comp_time_start || '-' || comp_time_end as period, thread# as thread,comp_time_end as hour, no_logs as count FROM ( SELECT TO_CHAR(completion_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24')|| ':00' comp_time_start ,TO_CHAR(completion_time +(1 / 24), 'hh24')|| ':00' comp_time_end, THREAD#,DEST_ID,COUNT(*) no_logs FROM v$archived_log, v$database WHERE completion_time BETWEEN SYSDATE - 1/24 AND SYSDATE AND standby_dest = 'NO' and database_role='PRIMARY' GROUP BY TO_CHAR(completion_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24'), TO_CHAR(completion_time +(1 / 24), 'hh24') ,THREAD#,DEST_ID  ) where rownum =1"
```

Here for index_unusable metrics, we tried to give "scrape_interval = "1h"" But this is not working and all the metrics mentioned in this file are getting collected every 60s as mentioned in the Grafana global scrape interval.

Looking forward for some suggestions to achieve the same.

Thanks!